# R: List of operators available for assignment

Tags: r, function, operators

I am interested it writing a few operators. Many characters are reserved and cannot be used `a` or `b` for example while others are currently used and I would not like them overwritten `+,-,>, and <` for example.  There are others which are unavailable for less clear reasons such as `$` or `@`.

I would like a list of characters that can be used as user written operators.

Thanks for your help,
Francis

Comment: `a` and `b` reserved by who? Certainly not by R. `$` and `@` are reserved for very clear reasons. Type `?"@"` and then `?"$"` in console

Comment: `?"Syntax"` shows a list of most common operators but it is not complete (e.g. `%in%` is missing).

Comment: @sgibb, `%in%` is covered by `?"Syntax"`, under `%any%`

Comment: If `a` is available, could someone please show me how to turn it into an operator?  `"a"<-function(...) bar(...)` does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "?"  and "!" can be overloaded.  I'm not going to reproduce the source code here, but take a look at the `sos` package and at the `cgwtools::splatnd` function for info on how to write your own unary (single-argument) operators.
I believe there's a tutorial on how to write `%foo%` binary operators but I forget where I saw it :-(